# What is the significance of the properties of TokenValidationParameters Class

Tags: .net, jwt

I'm new to JWT ,I was trying to implement it in one of my projects.While reading some of the articles on JWT I came across a class called TokenValidationParameters which have few properties that have to be initialized while implementing JWT. I want to know in detail use of these properties,why they are used, hopefully with an example

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication (JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer (options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new
                    SymmetricSecurityKey (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });

        services.AddMvc ();
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
    "Jwt": {
        "Key": "SecretKey",
        "Issuer": "http://localhost:64161/"
    }
}
```

Comment: [This class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet)?

Comment: @LutzHorn  Yes mate

Comment: The documentation should tell you the meaning of the properites. Which properties are you having trouble with?

Comment: The repo containing the code for this has some slightly better documentation in its [wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/ValidatingTokens). The source code for the logic that actually does token validation based on these parameters is [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/Validators.cs).